# Comparar duas strings e mostrar diferença entre elas

Tags: php, string

Acidentalmente cliquei em um *post* por aqui que foi editado e vi que o StackOverflow mostrou as diferenças da edição. Logo, uma lampada brilhou em cima da minha cabeça e agora que estou lidando em um projeto de CVT, pensei em um recurso de auditoria dos arquivos gerados, mas não só mostrando se está diferente do original ou não, algo longe de `str1 != str2`, quero que mostre inclusive o que foi alterado.

**Arquivo .txt enviado para auditoria**

```
A100000000000000000010000199000000000000000
E000000000000000000010000111000JARED-LETO--
```

**Arquivo .txt gerado pelo sistema** (esse sendo o original)

```
A000000000000000000020000129000000000000000
E000011110000000000010000441000HEATH-LEDGER
```

**O que eu espero**

```
A+000000000000000000+00001+9000000000000000
E0000++++0000000000010000++1000+++++-++++++
```

Acima um exemplo, trocando as diferenças por `+`.

Eu havia pensado em fazer o código mapeando posição por posição de cada caractere dos dois arquivos, mas ainda sim seria diferente de como é a aqui do fórum. Também procurei por alguma coisa no `github` e não encontrei. Alguém pode ter uma solução para isso ?

Comment: Você quer fazer tipo um _diff_ entre os dois arquivos. Vê se isso pode te ajudar [A diff implementation for PHP](http://code.stephenmorley.org/php/diff-implementation/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tem várias ferramentas que fazem isso, mas 'manualmente' pode fazer assim:

```
function get_str_difs($str1, $str2) {
    $old = htmlentities($str1);
    $new = htmlentities($str2);
    $from_start = strspn($old ^ $new, "\0");        
    $from_end = strspn(strrev($old) ^ strrev($new), "\0");

    $old_end = strlen($old) - $from_end;
    $new_end = strlen($new) - $from_end;

    $start = substr($new, 0, $from_start);
    $end = substr($new, $new_end);
    $new_diff = substr($new, $from_start, $new_end - $from_start);  
    $old_diff = substr($old, $from_start, $old_end - $from_start);

    $new = "$start<ins style='background-color:#ccffcc'>$new_diff</ins>$end";
    $old = "$start<del style='background-color:#ffcccc'>$old_diff</del>$end";
    return array('old' => $old, 'new' => $new);
}
```

Acabei por descobrir uma outra maneira simples de fazer:

```
function get_str_difs($str1, $str2) {
    $first = explode(" ", $str1);
    $second = explode(" ", $str2);
    $arrDif1 = array_diff($first,$second);
    $arrDif2 = array_diff($second,$first);

    $old = '';
    $new = '';
    foreach($first as $word) {
        if(in_array($word,$arrDif1)) {
            $old .= "<del style='background-color:#ffcccc'>" . $word . "</del> ";
            continue;
        }
        $old .= $word . " ";     
    }
    foreach($second as $word) {
        if(in_array($word,$arrDif2)) {
            $new .= "<ins style='background-color:#ccffcc'>" . $word . "</ins> ";
            continue;
        }
        $new .= $word . " ";   
    }
    return array('old' => $old, 'new' => $new);
}
```

Para usar as funções acima:

```
$str1 = "Olá, cá estou eu no Stack Overflow PT";
$str2 = "Hey, cá estou eu no Stack Exchange, SO PT";
$difs = get_str_difs($str1, $str2);
echo '<p>Str1:<b>' .$str1. '</b></p>';
echo '<p>Str2:<b>' .$str2. '</b></p>';
echo '<p><b>Difference:</b></p>';
echo '<p>' .$difs['old']. '</p>';
echo '<p>' .$difs['new']. '</p>';
```

Note que as duas têm diferentes mecânicas/resultados, é uma questão de ver qual prefere

Comment: Muito obrigado @Miguel, só consegui testar os códigos agora, deu certo e já implementei na minha aplicação, consegui o resultado que eu queria. Abraço fera !

Comment: E colocou logo certo sem testar?! hehe de nada @WilliamNovak, ainda bem que resultou